# Maintaining Updates for Software

Tags: updates, real-time-updates, automatic-updates

I'm currently designing a software application for work and I'm planning on installing the application on several computers. However the application will not be finished and there would be incremental updates from time to time I would have to do. Is there a way to update my software that is installed on multiple computer without having to go from one computer to the next?

Comment: There are several ways to handle this.  The program can update itself by checking for a later version on the server, downloading and installing with a script it invokes.  Another way is to add your server name to the apt-get repository list (/etc/apt/sources.list in Ubuntu) and then use cron to periodically apt-get update the program.

Comment: Hey Keith thx for the response, but I found what I was looking for online. Next time I would do some more research before I actually ask a question here and waste people's time. I'm building a C# application for work. What I needed was a way for the software to check for updates and update it without having to manually uninstall the software on each and ever machine I install my application on. I found the answer just a few minutes  ago . I need to build a ClickOnce application https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4BTLdIMYEY

Comment: Feel free to delete this question.